# HTML PAGE LINKING N

Tags: php, html, css, google-web-designer

So i am working on creating my website from the scratch and i will like the users of my website to verify themselves by logging in. I have a different html script for the log in page. I will like the verify button on the prompt page to be linked to the login page but whn i use the <"/a">, what link do i put in there?? Newbie here haha. Will appreciate some help.

Comment: Assuming that the login page is loginpage.php, then use `<a href="loginpage.php">Login</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I belive in the `<a>` element, you put href for the link. For example;
`<a href="url">random text</a>`, and to remove underline and font color, just do the css properties `text-decoration:none;` & `color:font-color;`

Comment: URL as in the web address, like stack overflow’s url is stackoverflow.com, but it could be an html file name in the same folder or host